# Android App can't save data to Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have created a sample app called NoteApp, that can save data to Parse. I have created the app in Parse as per the image below, and have created the app..which is still in progress.

I have created the object"testObject", I have matched the ID, and imported data(Ctrl+Shift+O)but when I try to run the app, and check the Parse dashboard, I can't see the object being created. I have tried this so many times, I don't know where the problem is. I just can't link my android app in eclipse with the Parse.com. the app can't create the object, hence I can't save data.

Here is the Application code, and the manifest file, and the image of the Parse.com Dashboard.

**NoteApplication.java**

```
package com.echessa.noteapp;![enter image description here][1]

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class NoteApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(NoteApplication.this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();

    }

}
```

**The Manifest File**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.echessa.noteapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.echessa.noteapp.NoteApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you put in breakpoints? Do you know that the save function is being triggered?

Comment: In my app, instead of `NoteApplication.this` I have `this`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Tell me more about the save function and the breakpoints...I am a new android programmer....

Comment: Actually I have done everything as per the tutorial sample...but I still don't know whats not going right....

Comment: Yes it looks like it should work. Do you have a table called "TestObject"?

Comment: Dude! It's not a good idea to do anything in this class which extends Application except initialize your Parse application. Make a different class and write that code there.

Comment: why you are saving your data in application class. write the code in different class. and make column which is in  your case "foo" in parse first.